# C# - Accessing the STDIN and STDOUT handles of a process without redirecting them

Tags: c#, .net, process

I'm trying to access the input and output streams of a process my application starts. My code is:

```
this.App = new Process();
this.App.StartInfo.FileName = this.AppPath;
this.App.StartInfo.Arguments = this.AppArgs;
this.App.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
this.App.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
this.App.Start();

ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (this.App.StandardOutput != null && !this.App.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
        {
            Console.Write((char)this.App.StandardOutput.Read());
        }
    }
}

this.listener = new Thread(ts);
this.listener.IsBackground = true;
this.listener.Start();

this.App.WaitForExit();
```

The code does work perfectly. It prints any output of the spawned process into console. The problem is, that the spawned process is a Source Dedicated Server, which doesn't like when it's STDIN/STDERR/STDOUT handles are redirected - throws up an error MessageBox and dies once it's closed. I have spent hours trying to mess with kernel32.dll, but failed.
I'm looking for a way to access the handles/output of the spawned process without redirecting them, as I'm obviously not allowed to do that.

Anyone?
Please.

Comment: I have also tried calling .ReadToEnd() on the App.StandardOutput stream, however, it doesn't change anything and I need to read the output in real time.

Comment: You should also note that your programm can block if you don't read both stdout and errout. It is possible that the budder gets full and will wait until it will be read.